# Unexpected RadioButton behavior

Tags: android, layout, radio-button

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/choices_group"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/choice_a"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Choice A" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/choice_b"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Choice B" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/choice_c"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Choice C" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/choice_d"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Choice D" />
</RadioGroup>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Why are the radio buttons superimposed over the text?

Comment: its a crappy work around but you could putting left padding on the radio button :/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Problem was with the padding. Once I removed the padding, everything worked as usual. This might be a bug.

Comment: For completeness: this is not a bug (at least not in Android). The label is given a transparent background image, which is a 9-patch with a lot of padding on the left side. This padding matches the size of the actual radio button image. If you override that padding, the layout will be screwed up.

Comment: This is fixed in api level 17, so I guess it is a bug.

Comment: @Thomas or kilaka do either have documentation on this definition/issue?

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Why are you using a relative layout? Put the radiogroup in a linearlayout, then put the lienarlayout in the relativelayout.</strike>

Try changing the radiobutton layout_width from fill_parent to wrap_content

Comment: why should I do that? RadioGroup itself inherits LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using `RelativeLayout`? That could be the problem.. Otherwise, I'd just increase the padding. I had this problem when using custom button images.

Comment: Yes, There are other components on the screen too. And my best option in that case is a RelativeLayout. I removed the android:padding="5dp" and everything works fine now. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Use [AppCompatRadioButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatRadioButton.html#), this issue has been release in AppCompat 22.1 library